# How can I get 8 bits output from 4 bit CPU?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, cpu-pipelines, shift-register

I am very new to Computer architecture. I am thinking to add one more output register to this 4 bit CPU as shown below. However, I am not sure should I connect the output register to the current CPU. Should I connect it just the same way as the current one and label the 2 output register as output A and output B? But if I connect it the same way, the input data from ALU to output registers will always be only 4 bits, how should I get 8 bits output from the two output registers?
[image]

Comment: If you connect another output register to the same bus as the first output register, the content of these registers will be the same if they are driven with the same clock and load signals. The real question is what do you want to achieve with the second register?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I really want to do by adding the second register is to get a total of 8 bits of output but I just don't understand how can I do it.